# Remap laptop brightness keys to Fn + Arrow keys

Tags: laptop, keymap

My new Dell laptop uses <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to adjust the brightness of the display.  How can I remap this to the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> key combinations that I'm used to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately,  keys cannot be remapped through software. Only hope would be if BIOS allows for remapping of keys but usually that is limited just to  and  switch.

I am not aware of BIOS that allows for other key combinations to be remapped.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible unless you change the hardware of your keyboard, the Fn key isn't seen my any software. When you press such a key together with another a special keycode is sent to your computer, pressing Fn alone does nothing.

But what you can do is to look for a [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script which allows you to do this, ask on their forum. ;-)

Comment: Nitpick: the BIOS is also software. The Fn key is not seen by the OS nor applications.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using Windows [here](http://www.thefreecountry.com/utilities/keyboard-mapping-hot-key-tools.shtml) are a few suggestions.

Comment: Do those work with the `Fn` key though?

Comment: No, the `Fn` key is specially handled in the keyboard controller (i.e., hardware) rather than through the OS (software), so on *almost* all laptops, it is not possible to modify its use.