# How to swap Fn and Ctrl keys on Lenovo L540

Tags: keyboard-layout, fn-key

I recently got a new computer and the <kbd>Fn</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys are driving me crazy.

Can anyone tell me the proper way to swap Function <kbd>Fn</kbd> and Control <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys on Lenovo L540?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/165932/remap-laptop-brightness-keys-to-fn-arrow-keys

Answer (score 0):

If under Windows, you could use AutoHotkey to [remap the keys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

There's also a section on their webpage dedicated to [special keys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys).